# Cannot convert 'auto' to EagerTensor of dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a `dataset` with 27 columns.
I created an `Autoencoder` for anomaly detection purposes as below:

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=(27,))

x = layers.Dense(20,activation='relu')(input_layer)
x = layers.Dense(14,activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(14, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(20,activation='relu')(x)

output = layers.Dense(27,activation='relu')(x)

AE = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam() 

loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError

iterator = iter(train_dataset) 
a = iterator.get_next() 
out = AE(a,training=True)
loss_value = loss_fn(a, out)
```

Why the following error appears?

```
TypeError: Cannot convert 'auto' to EagerTensor of dtype float
```

Comment: which line generating an error ?

Comment: @Shahrad Khedri, Can you share details of `train_dataset` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but I believe the issue is that you're using 
`tensorflow.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError`. If you use `tensorflow.keras.losses.MSE`, it might work, based on a similar problem I was having. Note that `tensorflow.keras.losses.MSE` is an alias of `tensorflow.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error`.

Comment: Found something else, according to [the webpage of tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError): this is a class. So I *think* in your code, you would have to add `()` in order to instantiate an object, and that should do the trick. I.e. `loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()`. I can't test this for you without data, though.

Answer (score 7):

### Disclaimer

This answer assumes that we have initially written:

```py
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
```

Note that without any example data, it's difficult to be sure this actually works in your case. But I solved a problem yielding the same error by learning about the following.

### Solution 1: using the MeanSquaredError class

The issue happens because `keras.losses.MeanSquaredError` is a class, [according to the tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError). Thus, you have to instantiate it first with parenthesis `()`, not alias it as if it were a function.

Thus, the following line fixes the problem:

```py
loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
```

### Solution 2: using the MSE function

Another option is to alias `keras.losses.MSE`, which is an alias of `keras.metrics.mean_squared_error`, [according to this site](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/mean_squared_error). If you view the source, you can see that this is a function outside of any class definition.

Thus, the following line fixes the problem:

```py
loss_fn = keras.losses.MSE
```

---

#### Important: the two solutions yield different results

The output of the two above solutions are not the same if the inputs have more than one dimension. The first one yields a scalar, the second one an array. In order for them to be the same, you would have to either:

- Pass a `NONE` type reduction when instantiating the class in solution 1. The loss value is now an array.

```py
loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
```

OR

- Additionally take the mean value from the output of the loss function in solution 2. The loss value is now a scalar.

```py
loss_value = tensorflow.reduce_mean(loss_fn(a, out))
```